# d3js map displays incorrectly in mobile chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, d3.js

I am relatively new to d3js, and trying to create a visualization of my quartet's concert schedule using a map.  My first attempt works great in a desktop chrome browser and desktop safari browser.

On my android device in mobile chrome, the map renders the entire globe incorrectly except for the United States.

http://test.chiaraquartet.net/topo/index.html

Any insight into what I am doing wrong/if there is a bug in d3 would be appreciated.

Here is the code in question:

```
  var center = [90, -38.7],
     ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
     graticule = d3.geo.graticule(),
     width = 500,
     height = 500,
     degrees = 180 / Math.PI,
     projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
     .scale(height / 2 - 1)
     .rotate(center)
     .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
     .clipAngle(90)
     .precision(.1)

 var graticule = d3.geo.graticule()()

 // Round to integer pixels for speed, and set pixel ratio.
 function roundRatioContext(context) {
   return {
     moveTo: function(x, y) { context.moveTo(Math.round(x * ratio), Math.round(y * ratio)); },
     lineTo: function(x, y) { context.lineTo(Math.round(x * ratio), Math.round(y * ratio)); },
     closePath: function() { context.closePath(); }
   };
 }

 var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
     .attr("width", width * ratio)
     .attr("height", height * ratio)
     .style("width", width + "px")
     .style("height", height + "px")

 var c = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

 var path = d3.geo.path()
     .projection(projection)
     .context(roundRatioContext(c));

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height)
     .append('g')

 var textbox = d3.select("body").append("div")
     .style('position', 'absolute')
     .attr('class', 'popup')
     .classed('hidden', true)

 var sphere = svg.append("path")
     .datum({type: "Sphere"})
     .attr("id", "sphere")
     .attr("d", path)

 var runner = queue()
   .defer(d3.json, 'world.json')
   .defer(d3.xhr('/concertrpc.php')
           .header('content-type', 'application/json')
           .post, JSON.stringify({
         params: [],
         id: 1
     }))
   .await(function(error, world, info) {
    if (error) return console.error(error);
    var features = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.states)
    var countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries)
    console.log(world)
    var concerts = JSON.parse(info.responseText)
    if (concerts.error) {
     console.log(concerts.error)
     return
    }
    concerts = concerts.result.concerts
    console.log(concerts)

   var globe = {type: "Sphere"},
       graticule = d3.geo.graticule()(),
       countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries),
       states = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.states),
       country_borders = topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.countries, function(a, b) { return a !== b }),
       state_borders = topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a.id !== b.id }),
       temp_context

   temp_context = path.context()
   path.context(null)
   svg.selectAll('.concert')
       .data(concerts, function(d) { return d.properties.id })
   .enter().append("path")
       .attr('class', 'concert')
       .attr('d', path)
       .on('mouseover', concertMouseover)
       .on('mouseout', function(d) {
           textbox.classed('hidden', true)
       })
   path.context(temp_context)

   d3.select('body').append('div').append('button')
       .attr('type', 'button')
       .text('This season')
       .on('click', function() {
           getConcertData('This season')
       })
   var zoom = d3.geo.zoom()
     .projection(projection)
     .duration(function(S) { return 2000 * Math.sqrt(S); }) // assume ease="quad-in-out"
     .scaleExtent([height / 2 - 1, Infinity])
     .on("zoom", function() {
       projection.clipAngle(Math.asin(Math.min(1, .5 * Math.sqrt(width * width + height * height) / projection.scale())) * degrees);
       c.clearRect(0, 0, width * ratio, height * ratio);
       c.strokeStyle = "#999", c.lineWidth = .25 * ratio, c.beginPath(), path(graticule), c.stroke();
       c.fillStyle = "#69d2e7", c.beginPath(), path(countries), c.fill();
       c.fillStyle = "#00f", c.beginPath(), path(states), c.fill();
       c.strokeStyle = "#fff", c.lineWidth = .5 * ratio, c.beginPath(), path(country_borders), c.stroke();
       c.strokeStyle = "#fff", c.lineWidth = .5 * ratio, c.beginPath(), path(state_borders), c.stroke();
       c.strokeStyle = "#000", c.lineWidth = .5 * ratio, c.beginPath(), path(globe), c.stroke();
       temp_context = path.context()
       path.context(null)
       svg.selectAll("path").attr("d",path);
       path.context(temp_context)
     })
     //.on("zoomend", transition);

   canvas
       .call(zoom)
       .call(zoom.event);
   sphere
       .call(zoom)

   function transition() {
     zoomBounds(projection, states.features[30]);
     canvas.transition()
         .ease("quad-in-out")
         .duration(2000) // see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/2045
         .call(zoom.projection(projection).event);
   }

   function zoomBounds(projection, o) {
     var centroid = d3.geo.centroid(o),
         clip = projection.clipExtent();

     projection
         .rotate([-centroid[0], -centroid[1]])
         .clipExtent(null)
         .scale(1)
         .translate([0, 0]);

     var b = path.bounds(o),
         k = Math.min(1000, .45 / Math.max(Math.max(Math.abs(b[1][0]), Math.abs(b[0][0])) / width, Math.max(Math.abs(b[1][1]), Math.abs(b[0][1])) / height));

     projection
         .clipExtent(clip)
         .scale(k)
         .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
   }
   })

 function concertMouseover(d) {
     var loc = projection(d3.select(this).datum().geometry.coordinates)
     textbox.style('top', loc[1] + "px")
     textbox.style('left', loc[0] + 15 + "px")
     textbox.text(d.properties.title)
     textbox.classed('hidden', false)
 }

 function getConcertData(request) {
     d3.xhr('/concertrpc.php')
     .header('content-type', 'application/json')
     .post(JSON.stringify({
         params: [request],
         id: 1
     }), function(error, info) {
         var concerts = JSON.parse(info.responseText)
         if (concerts.error) {
             console.log(concerts.error)
             return
         }
         var c = svg.selectAll('.concert')
             .data(concerts.result.concerts, function(d) { return d.properties.id })
         c.transition()
             .style('opacity', '1')

         c.enter()
             .append('path')
             .attr('class', 'concert')
             .attr('d', path)
             .on('mouseover', concertMouseover)
             .on('mouseout', function(d) {
                 textbox.classed('hidden', true)
             })
         c.exit().transition()
             .duration(1000)
             .style('opacity', '0')
             .remove()
     })
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what was causing the problem, but the culprit was in the topojson file generated by my attempts to combine a map of the countries of the world with a map of the states of the USA.  I found a different map of the world to use, and now the map displays the same way on both the phone and the desktop.